# Question on isogeny of abelian varieties and principal homogeneous spaces

Tags: proof-verification, algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties, group-schemes

I know that for an abelian variety $A$ over an algebraically closed field $k=\overline k$ and an ample line bundle $L$ on $A$, one can define an isogeny $\phi_L \colon A \rightarrow \mathrm{Pic}^0(A)$ by $x \mapsto \tau_x^* L \otimes L^{-1}$, where $\tau_x$ denotes the translation by $x$.

First, I assume that this goes through verbatim over a non algebraically closed field, assuming that $L$ is defined over $k$. Is it right, or am I missing something?

Second, does the above construction work if $A$ is just a principal homogeneous space over an abelian variety? That is, $k$ is not algebraically closed, $A$ has no $k$-rational points, but $A(\overline{k})$ is an abelian variety.
In this situation, do I still get a finite dominant morphism $\phi \colon A \rightarrow \mathrm{Pic}^0(A)$? My guess is that the same construction should still work, again provided that $L$ is a polarization defined over $k$.

As I am not very comfortable with non-closed fields, I would really appreciate some feedback on what I sketched above.

Comment: For an elliptic curve $\tau_x^*$ thus your map is defined over $k(O)$ the point such that $\tau_O^* = Id$ ?

Comment: This goes through verbatim for non algebraically closed fields, yes. More generally this should work for an abelian scheme over an arbitrary base scheme $S$.

Comment: @reuns Yes, once you fix the identity of the group law, $\tau_0=\mathrm{id}$.

Comment: @user45878 Are you referring to the part for abelian varieties over non closed fields, or also to the one about homogeneous spaces? Also, what is a reference I could look up?

Comment: Isn't your question to know over what field $\phi_L$ is defined ? Isn't it defined over $k(O)$, not $k$ ?

Comment: As a side remark, you might be interested in remarks 13.2 and 13.5 of http://jmilne.org/math/articles/1986b.pdf

Comment: @reuns Could you expand on why the morphism is defined over $k(0)$? I can see why intuitively, but I do not have a rigorous argument in mind.